# (SOLVED) Hum from Soundbar When Plugged into Audio Switch Box

Tags: audio, bluetooth

I have one of these audio switch boxes right here: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B073GWCRP3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B073GWCRP3)

I'm trying to use it to toggle between two different output devices on my entertainment center: a soundbar and a Bluetooth transmitter for when I want to listen via headphones. However, whenever I have the box switched to the Bluetooth transmitter, the soundbar starts making an audible hum. Turning the soundbar on and off is a bit of a pain, so I would like to find out what is causing the hum and how I can eliminate it.

I would appreciate any advice the community can offer. Thanks!

**UPDATE:** Here's what I've tried so far:

- Reversing one of the plugs, as both the soundbar and the bluetooth transmitter are two-prong devices.
- Ensuring both objects were plugged into the same outlet, which they were. In fact, the entire entertainment center runs off a single surge protector. Just to see if it made a difference, I plugged the soundbar into a different outlet on the other side of the room, but there was no change.
- Switching from an RCA-to-3.5mm to a 3.5mm-to-3.5mm cable, since I read somewhere that the latter is less prone to interference.
- Replacing the 3.5mm cable with a genuine dual-shielded 3.5mm cable.
- Turning off and unplugging all devices in my entertainment center except the soundbar.

The hum continued under all of these circumstances. It only stopped when a) the 3.5mm cable was plugged into the TV (even when the TV was off and unplugged), b) the 3.5mm cable was plugged into the audio switcher AND the switcher was switched to the soundbar, or c) the 3.5mm cable was unplugged from the soundbar itself. The hum was still present when the soundbar was plugged into the switcher, and the switcher was set to the other device. It was also present when the soundbar was not plugged into any device, meaning the 3.5mm plug end was exposed.

Based on the research I've done, my best guess is that the end of the 3.5mm cable is picking up electrical interference from somewhere *other* than the entertainment center. When I plug it into the TV, it's then shielded from any interference. However, this doesn't explain why there's still a hum when I plug the cable into the audio switcher and set the switcher to the other device. Is the prong somehow exposed when I switch away from it?

**UPDATE 2:** After further testing, I concluded that the problem was the switcher itself. Something inside was generating electrical noise, and the end of the audio cable to the soundbar was not properly shielded against it. Once I swapped the existing switcher for a different (and slightly higher-quality one) all of the noise went away.

I'm glad the problem is resolved, although I was hoping not to have to buy a new switcher. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason for that simple switch to induce hum is not the switch itself, but a [ground loop](https://www.circuitbread.com/ee-faq/what-is-a-ground-loop). This may be caused when there is some (very small) difference in AC voltage between two ground lines and/or two neutral lines into which different devices are plugged.

There are a few things to try to remedy that issue:

- If one (or both) of the devices have *unpolarized two wire* plugs (e.g., a "wall wart" with a two-prong plug, with both the same width), reverse *one* plug in the socket to see if that fixes the hum.
- Whether two-wire or grounded plugs are used, plug them all into the same mains socket. A power-strip may make this more convenient. And, if a device has an unpolarized two-prong connector, try inserting it in the power strip in both orientations to find the least noisy.
- In some cases, a leaky power supply can pass some AC hum. In  that case, you might try another power supply (of equal polarity, voltage and current rating), or put a 1:1 audio transformer in one of the audio cables to break the ground loop (a bit of DIY electrical know-how might be needed for that).